# Scala: Thread body with code outside run method

Tags: scala

I came across followinf scala code for a thread:

```
val myThread= new Thread() {
    if (xyz) ....do this
    else {
      ..do something else
    }
    var running = false
    def halt() = running = false
    override def run(): Unit = {
      running = true
      while (running) {
        ...call a function
        Thread.sleep(10000)
      }
    }
  }
```

I understand role run method would play. Additionally we have defined halt method.

But what about the remaining code. When does it get executed?

And is it possible to capture all this as a Future?

Answer (score 2):

In general, in Scala, code at the top level of a class (the code you've shown is the class definition for an anonymous subclass of `Thread`) is executed in sequence as the primary constructor for the class.

So

```scala
    if (xyz) ....do this
    else {
      ..do something else
    }
    var running = false
```

would all get executed just before the

```
val myThread= new Thread(){...}
```

assignment is made.

It would be executed in the thread that constructs the `Thread` object, *not* in the new thread that object defines.

(That new thread would only ever exist and run if `start()` is ever called on this object someday.)